# ajax is not working properly with alert box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I'm trying to do something with ajax.

```
    function DoSomething(url){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.SessionExpired === true)
                    alert('SessionExpired');
                else{
                    //DO Something
                }
            }
        });
        DoSomething else;
    }
```

before clicking on alert box 'OK' "DoSomething else" is getting executing.
I want that this will execute only after clicking on alert ok or after "Do Something" block.

Could you please guide me ??

Comment: It isn't working the way you want, **because its async call and it will create separate thread to make request and your execution to current code will proceed as normal.**. If you want to execute `DoSomething else`  code after clicking alert, place it exactly after alert (of make some function call to that code after alert).

Comment: "create separate thread" not really, javascript (in the browser) is single treaded

Comment: *threaded sorry not treaded

Answer (score 1):

$.ajax calls are async be default, your code 'DoSomething' is executing because the ajax call doesnt hault execution until it returns.

Put your `DoSomething()` inside the ajax callback

```
 function DoSomething(url){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data.SessionExpired === true)
                        alert('SessionExpired');
                        DoSomething();
                    else{
                        DoAnotherThing();
                    }
                }
            });

    }
```